# Redirect to new URL`s

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i want Redirect the old url`s to new address.

Redirect all

```
http://www.mysite.com/viewdownload/**/**
```

url`s to

```
http://www.mysite.com/download/viewdownload/**/**
```

example:

```
http://www.mysite.com/viewdownload/21/323

Should be Redirect to

http://www.mysite.com/download/viewdownload/21/323
```

or

```
http://www.mysite.com/viewdownload/13/961

Should be Redirect to

http://www.mysite.com/download/viewdownload/13/961
```

Comment: what component are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^(viewdownload)/(\d+)/(\d+)/?$ download/$1/$2/$3 [L,R=302,QSA]
```

If this does what you'd like it to after some testing, change `R=302` to `R=301`.

Comment: thanks this worked . but How this code if source url`s have a .html extension . i use **RewriteRule ^(viewdownload)/(\d+)/(\d+)/?.(html)$ download/$1/$2/$3 [L,R=302,QSA]** and worked , Is this correct?
sorry my en is bad

Comment: You'll want to make that `RewriteRule ^(viewdownload)/(\d+)/(\d+)\.html$ download/$1/$2/$3 [L,R=302,QSA]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache this is something for mod_rewrite / url rewriting & not Joomla.
You got the wrong keywords. Search for mod_rewrite or come back if you need more help.

Comment: sorry, I edited the question. yes i use the Apache server and .htaccess file